# Why does accessing the same resource with different user agents produce different responses?

Tags: http

I have something very strange I cannot explain, I have one host `thehostexample.com`:

1. when i go by Safari work well, it redirects automatically to `thehostexample.com/fr/`
2. when i go by `telnet` it tells me http 301, with the `thehostexample.com/fr/`
3. when i go by `wget` command ERREUR 403: Forbidden
4. when i access from a Perl script (`LWP::UserAgent` or `LWP::Simple`) ERREUR 403: Forbidden

I don't get it.  (I set the user agent to follow redirection.)

Please some help would be really nice.

Comment: It probably depends on the headers sent with each request and you didn't give too much info regarding this part.

Comment: Right, but i don't know the header the command "wget" send, either for   the command "get" in perl. How could i watch that without having to sniff the interface ?

Comment: perl's `GET` has option to display all headers. It is very likely that so does `wget`, but I think you can examine `wget --help` output yourself.

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be based on the user-agent header interacting with something on the server that is going "Eeek! A bot! A dirty dirty bot!"

Comment: Try faking your user-agent in your Perl script. Use http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ to get the correct value for Safari.

Comment: My user agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14" when i access from LWP::UserAgent cannot figure why it's not working. When i do a telnet access no complicate header ->GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com

Answer (score 0):

K i find out why it was not working, must be a bug from LWP::UserAgent !

If i declare my user agent like this :

> my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14');

Then it's not working, but if i declare it like this :

> my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
>
> $ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14');

Then it works, weird right ?

Hope it can help !